# Connecting android application to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am attempting to connect my android application to a mysql database using a wampp server and php scripting. After writing the php scripts and the java classes needed in order for this to work I am still unable to insert the data into the database. Here is my code:

```
public void submitAccount(View view) throws IOException {

    EditText info1 = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.username_edit_text));
    String message1 = info1.getText().toString();
    EditText info2 = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text));
    String message2 = info2.getText().toString();
    EditText info3 = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.retype_password_edit_text));
    String message3 = info3.getText().toString();
    EditText info4 = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text));
    String message4 = info4.getText().toString();
    EditText info5 = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.passphrase_edit_text));
    String message5 = info5.getText().toString();
    String operation = "register";
    AddDataToDatabase task = new AddDataToDatabase(this);
    task.execute(operation, message1, message2, message3, message4, message4);
    finish();
}
```

This is my CreateAccountActivity

```
herepublic class AddDataToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context myContext;
AddDataToDatabase(Context ctx){
    this.myContext=ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){
    String registration_url="http://192.168.0.19/webapp/register.php";
    String message=params[0];
    if(message.equals("register")){
        String username=params[1];
        String password=params[2];
        String retypedPassword=params[3];
        String email=params[4];
        String passphrase=params[5];
        try {
            URL url=new URL(registration_url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS= urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            try {
                BufferedWriter myBufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                String myData= URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("retypedPassword","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(retypedPassword,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("passphrase","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(passphrase,"UTF-8");
                myBufferedWriter.write(myData);
                myBufferedWriter.flush();
                myBufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration Complete!";

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(myContext,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}
This is my external java class AddDataToDatabase which I used in order to connect to the database.

```
<?php require "initialize.php";
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$retypedPassword=$_POST["retypedPassword"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$passphrase=$_POST["passphrase"];
$sql_query="insert into accounts values('username','$password','$retypedPassword','$email','$passphrase');";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
echo "Data insertion succes..";
}
else
{
echo "Data insertion error..".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

This is my register.php script

```
<?php
$db_name="android_accounts_db";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="root";
$server_name="localhost";
$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con){
}else{
}
?>
```

And this is my initialize.php script.
From what I had red on the internet there might be a problem with the registration_url variable in the AddDataToDatabase class. I have to mention that I used my IPV4 address. In the database I can see all my columns created in the accounts table but there is no data in them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to directly connect your app to an external database? Why not to use SQLite or a webservice?

Comment: Sidenote: You missed a `$` in `values('username'`. That will literally enter "username" in db, once you get it to work.

Comment: I am a beginner in Android. I learned how to use SQLite and now I just wanted to learn this way too. @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have already put the missing "$" and still nothing.

Comment: @Roberto, the three basic ways to store information in Android environment is to use SQLite, SharedPreferences or files. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) article from Google to better understand these concepts

Comment: The thing is that I have noticed that when I uninstall my app, I lose all the data in the database and also the files created to store the data. I want to be able to store the user's data even though he uninstalls the app. @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes

Comment: It is a bad bad practice to retain app data even after user uninstall your app. You can't make user to keep the data if he doesn't want to. The best you could do is to save your files in external storage, then they wouldn't be removed after app is deleted, however, user can delete them manually at any time

Comment: Is the name of you WebApp 'webapp"..?

Comment: Let me give you an example. So the user creates an account in my app. He uses my app for 3 days and then he uninstalls it. With the uninstall comes the loss of all the data. After this the user might want to reinstall the app. But he will have to register again because there will be no account to log in because his old account would have been lost. How can I approach this? That is why I tried to connect to an external database. From my point of view I could connect to the database from any device, search for my account and then log in. @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes

Comment: For this purpose, the best approach is to have a back end and provide this type of functionality through a WebService. Who is going to connect to the DB is not the Android Device, but the back end of your system. The app (front end) only make WS calls

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes but can you give me an example of a web service to use? I have never did something similar in my life so I would appreciate if you could point into the right direction.

Comment: Look for Back - Front end development, Web Development, WebServices, etc.